# Emirates doesn't ask me to choose flight seat when booking an online ticket

Tags: air-travel, seating, emirates

I would like to buy a ticket from Emirates airline online. As I go through steps of booking a flight on their website, it does not ask me to choose the seat and I wonder if there is such an option for Emirates airlines. I remember another airline which did have the step of choosing flight seat.

Comment: It's becoming more common to decouple ticket purchase from seat selection, and some airlines don't allow advance seat selection without being a premium passenger or paying an extra fee.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no. You book your ticket first then choose your seat:

> You can reserve seats through our Manage a Booking page. After entering your Emirates booking reference, you will be able to select your preferred seating option(s).
>   Please note that while every effort is made to satisfy seating requests, these are not guaranteed and could be changed without notice due to unexpected changes in aircraft, or due to operational requirements.

[Emirates](http://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/286745/can-i-reserve-seats-for-my-emirates-flights-and-how-do-i-do-this).